# Acceder a una subpágina en php con MVC

Tags: php, mvc, controller

Saludos a todos, estoy utilizando el patrón **MVC**, y utilizo un controlador para llamar a una vista, de la forma:
    http://example.com/locations/.
Hasta aquí me carga perfecto la vista, el problema es que tengo carpetas dentro de locations, las cuales son `destino1`, `destino2` y a su vez estas tienen un **index.php** para cargar la vista.

¿Es posible mandar a llamar la siguiente *url* mediante el modelo **MVC**, http://example.com/locations/destino1?

Este es mi controlador:

```
<?php namespace Controllers;

use Models\Location as Location;

class locationsController{

    private $location;

    public function index(){

    }
}
?>
```

mis carpetas están así:

```
Views

----->Locations

--------------->destino1

--------------->destino2

--------------->destino3
```

y quisiera acceder al **index.php** del `destino1`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el framework que estas utilizando?

Comment: No estoy utilizando ningún framework, ¿Cúal me recomiendas para poder realizar lo que quiero?

Comment: Existen varios. Yo utilizo Codeigniter, pero existen varios como Laravel, Symphony, etc. Yo te recomendaría que pruebes unos cuantos y veas cual se acomoda a tus necesidades. Con cada uno podrías hacer excelente aplicaciones.

Comment: En principio, parece que es una cuestión de configuración del servidor web. Dependiendo del que uses (apache, nginx, etc...) se configura de una u otra forma, pero básicamente tienes que indicar que el índice por defecto es el fichero index.php.

Answer (score 1):

si entiendo bien tienes esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no dices como estas cargando las vistas por lo que no puedo ayudarte mucho.

¿tienes un archivo .htaccess?
Si es así, tendrías que configurar como envías las variables en la url y según lo que recibes decidir que controlador usar y el controlador se encargara de mostrar la vista dependiendo de que parámetros recibas.

los frameworks hacen esto con una especie de "controlador general" que solo se encarga de cargar el controlador que corresponda y ejecutar un método según las variables.

en el fondo lo que necesitas es crear algo que controle las rutas, si no quieres complicarte lo mejor es usar un framework (aunque tienen su tiempo de aprendizaje).

Comment: Si gustas pasame tu correo y te envio mi proyecto para que veas como lo tengo estructurado

Comment: envés de enviar por correo deberías especificar mas en tu pregunta para que otros también puedan responder y en caso de solucionar el problema... otros que tengan un problema similar lo puedan resolver.